# changing last maximum with first minimum using arrays

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a c++ program that when a given a sequence, it tries to change the first minimum with the last maximum. My code is tested on my university's e-judge. It passes 32 test cases, but gets stuck at the 32 one. Can you spot what might be wrong, about the better Int, it's just for a bigger number. the program statement is that input contains a natural n – the quantity of numbers in a sequence, then n numbers – elements of a sequence.
Output should be the changed sequence of numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <cmath>
#include <climits>
#define SIZE 100000

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    long long int a[SIZE], min, max;
    int n, min_i, max_i; min = 0x7fffffffffffffff; max = -1;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
        if (a[i] < min) { min = a[i]; min_i = i; }
        if (a[i] >= max) { max = a[i]; max_i = i; }
    }
    a[max_i] = min; a[min_i] = max;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, for the largest maximum number, I tried, int_max, uint_max, better INT, all the same when it comes to failing the 32nd test case.

Comment: The e-judge might intentionally set out to fail on certain tricks like your sentinel value for `min`.  I would read all values in, and _then_ calculate min/max.  I'd initialize both `min_i` and `max_i` to 0, and both `min` and `max` to `a[0]`.  Then begin looping from 1.

Comment: @paddy i think just initialising `min_i` and `max_i` to `0` would be sufficient?

Comment: @paddy, I thought of that it would take me three loops to do it, one for storing, one for calculating min/max, one for outputting, I avoided that with doing two things in one loop, then second loop for outputting.

Comment: @AlanBirtles not on its own as currently written.  This code relies on `min` containing the value `a[min_i]`, which is not known.  Adding tests inside the loop to cover the first case is messy, and looking up the value in the array instead of memoizing the min is not ideal.  That's why I'd _personally_ separate it out, for both clarity and performance.  But sure, if you initialize `min` to `LLONG_MAX` and `min_i` to 0, it would be fine.  The most likely cause here is the bogus value `BETTER_INF`.

Comment: @paddy I changed the code, it still fails 32nd test case.

Comment: are you sure the numbers provided by the test are all integers?

Comment: @Yes, 100 sure, for example, before, there was a similar problem, when I used LLong max, it didn't work, but, with better inf, it worked. so I am assuming the algorithm is just working fine, something with maximum value assigned to min. for initiating min _i to 0, I don't have to, because the input would be between -1 < input < infinity or big number, so there would an automatic initiation.

Comment: I would just handle the initialization by reading a single number before the loop, and then setting both `min` and `max` to both. That way you are guaranteed that all the values you work with in the loop are within range.

Comment: If `n` is zero or negative, your program just crashes with not initialized values `max_i` and `min_i`. What is natural number? Some mathematicians include 0 to natural numbers.

Comment: If no numbers are smaller than the initial `min`, `min_i` remains indeterminate. What are the actual ranges of your inputs?

Comment: input is n terms, terms are random and as big as you can think, that is n >= 0

Comment: I think the problem lies with `BETTER_INF`. Where you have defined it, all bits are set (which is maximum value if it's unsigned) but inside main, you have assigned `min` (which is a long long int) to `BETTER_INF.` The implicit cast will set the rest of the leading bits to 1 and so the resulting number would be -1 (since `min` is not unsigned). Instead you should set `min` to be the maximum number possible for long long int which is `0x7fffffffffffffff` (all bits sets to 1 except the first bit).

Comment: @lucieon how can I accomplish that?

Comment: Just define `min` inside main just like `max`: `long long int min = 0x7fffffffffffffff;`

Comment: @lucieon like what I did above, still didn't work!

Comment: What is `n` in the failing test case? Could it be that it is <=0 or > `SIZE`? In both cases your program is wrong. Also note that you defined `min` and `max` twice. Doesn't that give warnings from your compiler? Also this `freopen` looks a bit strange. Why not use `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` instead?

Comment: Consider the case of one element, with the maximum possible value, and think about what `min_i` becomes.

Comment: You do not test for invalid inputs.  It's possible that the e-judge is testing for proper handling of some bogus input and expecting no output.  Hard to postulate without seeing the exact problem statement.  I am assuming that based on the value `SIZE`, there is a written guarantee that `n` will never exceed that number.

Answer (score 0):

- Is it guaranteed that the input sequence (`n` in your code) is with no more than `SIZE` (100000 in the code) elements? 
  Are you allowed to use dynamic memory allocation instead?
- Is it guaranteed that `n` will be at least `1`? 
  If it is `0` both `min_i` and `max_i` would have [indeterminate state](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) which could crash your program when you use them as indexes: `a[max_i] = min; a[min_i] = max;`.
- If the above two assumptions are valid, I would do what @paddy and @Frodyne already suggested and initialize all variables with valid data before going into the main loop:

```cpp
size_t min_i = 0;
size_t max_i = 0;
cin >> a[0];
min = a[0];
max = a[0];
for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) { ... }
```